# can't import libraries installed in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, pygame, anaconda

I usually try to install libraries for python by :

```
sudo apt-get install python-lib name
```

and when the operation is complete I can't import the library I have tried this for pygame,tk and other libs. I also usually can't install any library with pip because it gives me a bunch of error and I have also tried installing packages with their source by :

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

and usually I get errors on the "build" part.

What should I do?

Comment: This question is way too vague. "I Can't import the library". The errors you get in pip and on the "build" part would be good to share but I think you might need to go to the Ubuntu forums about this issue.

Comment: Which errors does pip give?

Comment: firts try install with `sudo pip` then with`sudo apt-get`. Both should install in correct folder. `tkinter` is installed with python so you don't have to install it. Use `import Tkinter` for Python 2 or `import tkinter` for Python 3.

Comment: do you get error with import ? Show full error message. Do you run script like this `python script.py` ?  Do you have shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python` in first line of script ? Did you use `chmod u+x script.py` to make it executable ?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Ubuntu? Probably yes. Ubuntu have two versions of python preinstalled: `python2.7` and `python3.4`. Your command is installing library for `python2.7`. If you are writing your script for python 3.4, then you fail with import libraries. Try using `sudo apt-get install python3-packagename` to install library for python3.

edit:
are you using your `pip` command with `sudo`? `sudo pip instal ...`?

Comment: no i use python2.7 anaconda and no i dont use pip with sudo

Comment: i just uninstalled anaconda and the packages i could not import in anaconda now i can import in the default python

Comment: anaconda has own program to install modules - conda. And it install Python and modules in own folder.

Comment: OP wrote that he's using `sudo apt-get install python-lib name` for installing. So the problem was here: apt-get installs in default python `dir` but he was launching another instance of python. Regarding errors `building` or `pip` install - it's often caused by lack of dependencies or permissions.